# Need to transfer data from website to googlesheets

Tags: html, xml, xpath, google-sheets, statistics

I would like to transfer fantasy data from http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/hstats.cgi?pos=0&sort=4&game=d&colA=0&daypt=0&xavg=6&show=1&fltr=00 to Google Sheets.

The intent is to have it updated once daily for analytical purposes.

ive tried =importxml but it won't populate the information into seperate cells. It just populates it all into 1 cell.

Comment: Do you want to get all tables or just 1 table? Also, can you show your `importxml` command?

Comment: The main issue is the data you are trying to import is not properly formatted. It is impossible to directly import it to sheets as a table. If you can find an alternate site that is properly formatted, then we can look into that.

There are certain limitations to `import` functions of sheets. First of all, the site should not be dynamically populated (via javascript and similar methods). Another one is that the data should be in proper tags (for `xpath` of `importxml` and `table` of `importhtml`) or at least have consistent delimiters (for `importdata` ) for us to catch them properly.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/hstats.cgi?pos=0&sort=4&game=d&colA=0&daypt=0&xavg=6&show=1&fltr=00"),
 5000, 10), 
 "limit 25 offset 167", 0)),,9^9)), 
 "<\/\w+>|<\w+.*?>", ), " "))
```

[image]

Comment: I never knew it would be possible with that kind of formatting. Upvoted for generating a great answer.